# How to apply a function to a pandas dataframe when using external arguments and multiple columns?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have an array my_arr:

```
[10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
```

I have a pandas df, `my_df`:

| id | start_index | end_index | array_sums |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |  |

I want the Array sums field to equal the sum of the array from the start_index to the end_index, however if the end_index is smaller than the start_index then I want to sum of the values in the start_index to the end of the array and the values from the start of the array to the start_index. Essentially a sum from start index to end index where the array is like a loop.

```
def my_func(my_arr, start, end):
    if end >= start:
        consumption = sum(my_arr[start:end+1])
    if end < start:
        consumption = sum(my_arr[start:6])+sum(my_arr[0,end+1])
    return consumption
```

and I'm computing the following to get array_sums

```
my_df['array_sums'] = my_df.apply(lambda x: my_func(my_arr,x['first_week'],x['last_week']),axis=1)
```

But I get the following error: "too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed".

Can someone provide some help on how I can achieve the desired result? The result should be

| id | start_index | end_index | array_sums |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | 140 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 210 |

Comment: is the desired outcome correct? why are are `array_sums` single digit numbers?

Comment: @enke -- just fixed it... thanks for catching that!

Comment: you did everything perfect. just had a typo. change sum(my_arr[0,end+1]) to sum(my_arr[0:end+1])

Comment: @David thank you so much! I've been at this for 3 hours and am new to my company, and couldn't figure out what to do since no one has time to spend time debugging with me. I appreciate your help immensely.